# Pass Data From One Controller To another Using Spring DI

Tags: spring, javafx, dependency-injection

I have a javafx application that uses Spring DI framework.

I use this class, `SpringFXMLLoader<S,T>` , to get Parent node and related controller from [this](https://github.com/james-d/SpringFXExample/blob/master/Spring%20JavaFX%20Example/src/springfx/fxml/SpringFXMLLoader.java) github repository by James Denver.

The problem i have is passing data from one controller to another e.g a selected User from table in one controller and pass the selected user to another controller and display user specific information.

This is what i tried, which didn't work as the object i passed is null in the `UserDetailController`

```
SpringFXMLLoader<Parent, UserDetailController> loader =
        SpringFXMLLoader.create()
            .applicationContext(applicationContext)
            .location(getClass().getResource("/fxml/userDetail.fxml"))
            .build();
Parent userDetailNode = loader.load();
            UserDetailController userDetailController = loader.getController();
            User user = tblUsers.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            
            userDetailController.setUser(user);
rootController.getViewContentPane().setCenter(userDetailNode);
```

How can i pass data from one controller to another in this case, i.e Spring DI injects beans.

How can data be passed around javafx controllers when using Spring DI?

## Update

Anyone need extra info, i am ready to provide anytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. The problem with my approach at first beats the logic of using dependency injection, as it introduced dependencies between controllers.

## Solution

Using `Spring` Publish and Listen `ApplicationEvents`.

1. I created an event that takes a `User` object.
2. `UsersController` registered as a `Publisher` publishes this event with the selected `User`
3. `UserDetailController` registered as a `Listener` listen and get the selected `User` from the event